# Editing form on Symfony2 without AJAX or passing ID

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to edit an entry in the database, but I don't know how to do it without passing an ID or with AJAX.
Isn't there a way to choose the entry to edit in a dropdown/select box and then, when the user selects it, a textbox would appear just beneath the dropdown/select box for him to enter the new name of the entry ?

Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend you to figure out how html, http and php work separately before you start using symfony.

Comment: I perfectly know how it works. What I meant is that I don't how, on the controller part, how to get the id of the selected dropdown.

Comment: You need to pass it somehow, as per how html and http allow to do.